# Cannot set my headers with axios for bible api

Tags: javascript, axios

Here is my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API = axios.create({ baseURL: 'https://api.scripture.api.bible' });

API.defaults.headers.common['api-key'] = 'MY_API_KEY';
API.defaults.headers.get['content-type'] = 'text';
API.defaults.headers.get['include-titles'] = false;
API.defaults.headers.get['include-verse-numbers'] = false;

export const getEnglishVerse = (verseId) => API.get(`/v1/bibles/65eec8e0b60e656b-01/verses/${verseId}`);
export const getItalianVerse = (verseId) => API.get(`/v1/bibles/41f25b97f468e10b-01/verses/${verseId}`);
```

The problem is that the last three headers don't work. There is the documentation:
https://scripture.api.bible/livedocs#/Verses/getVerse

Here is what I want to set:[image]

In swagger all is good, but the content of my response json is this:

```
<p class="p"><span data-number="16" data-sid="JHN 3:16" class="v">16</span>Perciocchè Iddio ha tanto amato il mondo, ch'egli ha dato il suo unigenito Figliuolo, acciocchè chiunque crede in lui non perisca, ma abbia vita eterna. </p>
```

I just want the verse in text, not in html (default setting), but my three last headers that I try to set are wrongly set.

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in the query string that content-type should be placed: ...?content-type=text...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the bible this code
The `content-type` is text is still beta. It returned JSON even if set text.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const getBible = async (bibleId, verseId) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get(
            `https://api.scripture.api.bible/v1/bibles/${bibleId}/verses/${verseId}`,
            {
                params: {
                    'content-type': 'text',
                    'include-notes': false,
                    'include-titles': false,
                    'include-chapter-numbers': false,
                    'include-verse-numbers': true,
                    'include-verse-spans': false,
                    'use-org-id': false
                },
                headers: {
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                    'api-key' : '************ your api key *********'
                }
            }
        );
        return Promise.resolve(resp.data);
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
};

const EnglishVerse ='65eec8e0b60e656b-01'
const ItalianVerse ='41f25b97f468e10b-01'

getBible(EnglishVerse,'JHN.3.16')
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log('English: ' + result.data.content);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
    
getBible(ItalianVerse,'JHN.3.16')
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log('Italian: ' + result.data.content);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Result

```
$ node get-bible.js
{
  data: {
    id: 'JHN.3.16',
    orgId: 'JHN.3.16',
    bookId: 'JHN',
    chapterId: 'JHN.3',
    bibleId: '65eec8e0b60e656b-01',
    reference: 'John 3:16',
    content: "     [16] For God loved the world, and this is how: he gave his one and only Son, so that everyone who trusts in him shouldn't die, but have eternal life. \n",
    verseCount: 1,
    copyright: 'Dr. Jonathan Gallagher. Released under Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 Unported License. Version 4.1. For corrections send email to jonathangallagherfb
v@gmail.com',
    next: { id: 'JHN.3.17', number: '17' },
    previous: { id: 'JHN.3.15', number: '15' }
  },
  meta: {
    fums: '<script>\n' +
      'var _BAPI=_BAPI||{};\n' +
      "if(typeof(_BAPI.t)==='undefined'){\n" +
      `document.write('\\x3Cscript src="'+document.location.protocol+'//cdn.scripture.api.bible/fums/fumsv2.min.js"\\x3E\\x3C/script\\x3E');}\n` +
      `document.write("\\x3Cscript\\x3E_BAPI.t('b588e0e1-b3a1-4895-91bf-ab57e7feb91c');\\x3C/script\\x3E");\n` +
      `</script><noscript><img src="https://d3a2okcloueqyx.cloudfront.net/nf1?t='b588e0e1-b3a1-4895-91bf-ab57e7feb91c'" height="1" width="1" border="0" alt="" style="height: 0; wi
dth: 0;" /></noscript>`,
    fumsId: 'b588e0e1-b3a1-4895-91bf-ab57e7feb91c',
    fumsJsInclude: 'cdn.scripture.api.bible/fums/fumsv2.min.js',
    fumsJs: "var _BAPI=_BAPI||{};if(typeof(_BAPI.t)!='undefined'){ _BAPI.t('b588e0e1-b3a1-4895-91bf-ab57e7feb91c'); }",
    fumsNoScript: '<img src="https://d3btgtzu3ctdwx.cloudfront.net/nf1?t=b588e0e1-b3a1-4895-91bf-ab57e7feb91c" height="1" width="1" border="0" alt="" style="height: 0; width: 0;"
/>'
  }
}
English:      [16] For God loved the world, and this is how: he gave his one and only Son, so that everyone who trusts in him shouldn't die, but have eternal life.

{
  data: {
    id: 'JHN.3.16',
    orgId: 'JHN.3.16',
    bookId: 'JHN',
    chapterId: 'JHN.3',
    bibleId: '41f25b97f468e10b-01',
    reference: 'EVANGELO DI S. GIOVANNI 3:16',
    content: "     [16] Perciocchè Iddio ha tanto amato il mondo, ch'egli ha dato il suo unigenito Figliuolo, acciocchè chiunque crede in lui non perisca, ma abbia vita eterna. \n
",
    verseCount: 1,
    copyright: 'Public domain',
    next: { id: 'JHN.3.17', number: '17' },
    previous: { id: 'JHN.3.15', number: '15' }
  },
  meta: {
    fums: '<script>\n' +
      'var _BAPI=_BAPI||{};\n' +
      "if(typeof(_BAPI.t)==='undefined'){\n" +
      `document.write('\\x3Cscript src="'+document.location.protocol+'//cdn.scripture.api.bible/fums/fumsv2.min.js"\\x3E\\x3C/script\\x3E');}\n` +
      `document.write("\\x3Cscript\\x3E_BAPI.t('350cce2a-a308-43cd-9073-2bd8b87eef4d');\\x3C/script\\x3E");\n` +
      `</script><noscript><img src="https://d3a2okcloueqyx.cloudfront.net/nf1?t='350cce2a-a308-43cd-9073-2bd8b87eef4d'" height="1" width="1" border="0" alt="" style="height: 0; wi
dth: 0;" /></noscript>`,
    fumsId: '350cce2a-a308-43cd-9073-2bd8b87eef4d',
    fumsJsInclude: 'cdn.scripture.api.bible/fums/fumsv2.min.js',
    fumsJs: "var _BAPI=_BAPI||{};if(typeof(_BAPI.t)!='undefined'){ _BAPI.t('350cce2a-a308-43cd-9073-2bd8b87eef4d'); }",
    fumsNoScript: '<img src="https://d3btgtzu3ctdwx.cloudfront.net/nf1?t=350cce2a-a308-43cd-9073-2bd8b87eef4d" height="1" width="1" border="0" alt="" style="height: 0; width: 0;"
/>'
  }
}
Italian:      [16] Perciocchè Iddio ha tanto amato il mondo, ch'egli ha dato il suo unigenito Figliuolo, acciocchè chiunque crede in lui non perisca, ma abbia vita eterna.
```

[image]

This `curl` command can get the all of bible id list

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.scripture.api.bible/v1/bibles' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'api-key: ************ your api key *********' > bible-ids.txt
```

```
{"data":[{"id":"472735b48a27b402-01","dblId":"472735b48a27b402","relatedDbl":null,"name":"The New Testament in Ahirani language","nameLocal":"प्रेम संदेश","abbreviation":"NTAii20","abbreviationLocal":"NTAii20","description":"The New Testament in Ahirani language, 2020","descriptionLocal":"प्रेम संदेश, नवा करार, 2020","language":{"id":"ahr","name":"Ahirani","nameLocal":"Ahirani","script":"Devanagari","scriptDirection":"LTR"},"countries":[{"id":"IN","name":"India","nameLocal":"India"}],"type":"text","updatedAt":"2022-01-07T17:50:52.000Z","audioBibles":[]},{"id":"0c2ff0a5c8b9069c-01","dblId":"0c2ff0a5c8b9069c","relatedDbl":null,"name":"Nend Portions - Mark","nameLocal":"MAK Yakŋ Ohɨrand Ya Imbɨr Makɨv Mpamar","abbreviation":"NendNP03","abbreviationLocal":"NendNP03","description":null,"descriptionLocal":"Mark in Nend","language":{"id":"anh","name":"Nend","nameLocal":"Nend","script":"Latin","scriptDirection":"LTR"},"countries":[{"id":"PG","name":"Papua New Guinea","nameLocal":"Papua New Guinea"}],"type":"text","updatedAt":"2022-01-07T05:09:04.000Z","audioBibles":[]},{"id":"b17e246951402e50-01","dblId":"b17e246951402e50","relatedDbl":null,"name":"Biblica® Open New Arabic Version 2012","nameLocal":"كتاب الحياة مجانى","abbreviation":"ONAV","abbreviationLocal":"KEHM","description":"Holy Bible","descriptionLocal":"ا‫لكتاب المقدس","language":{"id":"arb","name":"Arabic, Standard","nameLocal":"العربية","script":"Arabic","scriptDirection":"RTL"},"countries":[{"id":"EG","name":"Egypt","nameLocal":"Egypt"},{"id":"SA","name":"Saudi Arabia","nameLocal":"Saudi Arabia"}],"type":"text","updatedAt":"2022-01-12T09:15:43.000Z","audioBibles":[{"id":"26b7a1cd2f8f4878-01","name":"Biblica® Open New Arabic Version 2012, Audio Edition","nameLocal":"Ketab El Hayat Majani/كتاب الحياة مجانى","dblId":"26b7a1cd2f8f4878"}]},{"id":"b7ad344da9c39262-01","dblId":"b7ad344da9c39262","relatedDbl":null,"name":"Arapaho Luke","nameLocal":"Hethadenee waunauyaunee vadan Luke Vanenāna","abbreviation":"arp","abbreviationLocal":"ARP","description":"common","descriptionLocal":"common","language":{"id":"arp","name":"Arapaho","nameLocal":"Arapaho","script":"Latin","scriptDirection":"LTR"},"countries":[{"id":"US","name":"United States of America","nameLocal":"United States of America"}],":[]}]}
```